# Why is memcpy_P behaving this way in this arduino sketch?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded, avr

I'm using `memcpy_P` to copy a row from a `PROGMEM` 2d array of structs into a buffer. The number of columns is specified by `COLS_PER_FRAME`.

`memcpy_P(buf, FRAMES[i], COLS_PER_FRAME)` works as expected.

If I instead specify the source array as (`FRAMES + (buffer_offset++)`) that works the same, and the code compiles into less space. This is surprising to me because I expected that it should be `FRAMES + (buffer_offset++ * COLS_PER_FRAME)`.

Shouldn't it end up getting the array offset by 1 byte, not one whole row? Any why is the compiled code smaller?

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

typedef struct {
  const uint8_t anode : 3;
  const uint8_t cathode : 3;
} Led;

const uint8_t NUM_FRAMES = 11;
const uint8_t COLS_PER_FRAME = 6;
const  Led FRAMES[NUM_FRAMES][COLS_PER_FRAME] PROGMEM = {
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 1, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 6} },
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 1, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 1, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 1, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 6, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 6, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 5}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 6, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 7, .cathode = 1}, {.anode = 7, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 1, .cathode = 5}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 6, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 7, .cathode = 2}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 7}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 0, .cathode = 6}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 5}, {.anode = 5, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 7, .cathode = 3}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 7}, {.anode = 1, .cathode = 7} },
  { {.anode = 1, .cathode = 6}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 5}, {.anode = 6, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 3, .cathode = 7}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 0}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
  { {.anode = 3, .cathode = 6}, {.anode = 2, .cathode = 6}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 5}, {.anode = 7, .cathode = 4}, {.anode = 4, .cathode = 7}, {.anode = 0, .cathode = 0} },
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("hello");
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t buffer_offset = 0;

  static Led buf[COLS_PER_FRAME] = {0};

  for (int8_t i = 0; i < NUM_FRAMES; ++i) {
    // 2076 bytes compiled with pointer offset (FRAMES + buffer_offset)
    memcpy_P(buf, FRAMES + buffer_offset, COLS_PER_FRAME);
    buffer_offset += 1;

    // 2082 bytes compiled with array index (FRAMES[i])
    // memcpy_P(buf, FRAMES[i], COLS_PER_FRAME);

    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < COLS_PER_FRAME; ++j) {
      Serial.print('a');
      Serial.print(buf[j].anode);
      Serial.print(" c");
      Serial.print(buf[j].cathode);
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);
}
```

Output (correctly reproduces the input):

```
  a0 c1, a1 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0, a5 c6,
  a0 c2, a2 c1, a2 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0,
  a0 c3, a1 c2, a3 c1, a3 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0,
  a1 c3, a3 c2, a4 c1, a0 c0, a0 c0, a0 c0,
  a0 c4, a2 c3, a4 c2, a5 c1, a5 c0, a0 c0,
  a1 c4, a4 c3, a5 c2, a6 c1, a6 c0, a0 c0,
  a0 c5, a2 c4, a5 c3, a6 c2, a7 c1, a7 c0,
  a1 c5, a3 c4, a6 c3, a7 c2, a0 c7, a0 c0,
  a0 c6, a2 c5, a5 c4, a7 c3, a2 c7, a1 c7,
  a1 c6, a3 c5, a6 c4, a3 c7, a4 c0, a0 c0,
  a3 c6, a2 c6, a4 c5, a7 c4, a4 c7, a0 c0,
```

Comment: look up pointer arithmetic. `+` adds sizeof type

Comment: what if I actually do want bytes?

Comment: then you have to cast the pointer first to uint8_t*

Answer (score 2):

`a[2]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a+2)` (to the point that `2[a]` is perfectly valid and equivalent). Since indexing and pointer arithmetic are the same thing, adding to a pointer must advance the pointer by that many *elements*, not bytes. (Same for subtraction.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
   uint8_t  u8;
   uint32_t u32;
   uint64_t u64;

   printf( "%p %p\n", ( void * )&u8,  ( void * )( &u8  + 1 ) );
   printf( "%p %p\n", ( void * )&u32, ( void * )( &u32 + 1 ) );
   printf( "%p %p\n", ( void * )&u64, ( void * )( &u64 + 1 ) );
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
0x7ffde70ae5eb 0x7ffde70ae5ec  // Delta = 1
0x7ffde70ae5ec 0x7ffde70ae5f0  // Delta = 4
0x7ffde70ae5f0 0x7ffde70ae5f8  // Delta = 8
```

So all you need is this:

```c
const Led (*p)[COLS_PER_FRAME] = FRAMES;

for (int8_t i = 0; i < NUM_FRAMES; ++i) {
    memcpy_P(buf, p++, sizeof(*p));
    ...
}
```